# Where to store the user Id, while using a network database

Tags: c#, database, registry

We have a C#.Net application which uses a network database. I mean to say that many instances of the application will access the same db from different machines. So if I have to store the user-id to show the user while re-logging in, where can I store it?

The options i have are:
- Storing it in a local file in application directory. (But the problem is that the application is installed using Click Once. When the application is updated the application directory is being changed. May be I am missing something here.)
- Storing in the registry. 
Are there any other?

Can some one please suggest what to do? Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: What do you mean by relogging in? Why not use Session in Sql Mode, if this is just a web server farm?

Comment: @Tejs I want to auto fill the userId in the User Id text field in the login form if the user has already logged in once. I want to know the userId before asking the db.

Comment: @Prakash, just be careful not to store any plain-text passwords.

Comment: @Branko yeah, sure. I am using to store only userId.

Answer (score 3):

There are buil-int locations for this kind of stuff see [`Environment`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx) - specifically:

- `ApplicationData` (user-specific roaming)
- `LocalApplicationData` (user-specific non-roaming)
- `CommonApplicationData` (not user-specific)

Comment: Thank you. What about the case when the application folder is modified when the application is updated.(as mentioned in the question). I also mean to ask why is it the application folder is being modified.

Comment: these locations are outside the application folder - so an update of the contents of the application folder (like a new EXE/DLL etc.) won't change anything you have put in those locations...

Comment: The application we installed through click once is installing in location "c:\Users\Prakash\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\<random value>\<random value>\<app installed folder>" And this app installed folder is being modified. Does this path come under LocalApplicationPath or not?

Comment: I don't use ClickOnce so I am not sure - I suggest you just try it by checking for the values the above locations return in your scenario

Answer (score 1):

Generally you want to store any data that needs to persist between sessions, and is user specific in the registry, or the user AppData folder. Normally for small things (i.e. ids, basic settings etc....) the registry is the best place. Just make sure to stick it under HKCU\Software\Your company name\your program name. Although if the data is sensitive you should be careful where you place it, and it should be encryptedto protect it from basic snooping. If it's data that isn't sensitive though then the registry is a good place to put it.

This assumes of course that the installation and configuration doesn't need to be xcopy portable (i.e. a user could just copy the installation folder to a new place/computer and have everything work as normal). If that's the case then you'll want to store it under the installation directory.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to store the UserID on the local, keep it in some kind of configuration file, mabe under a "LastLogin" entry. Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7148745/c-encrypt-text-output/7149528) and specifically [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7148745/c-encrypt-text-output/7149528#7149528) for more information.

Comment: So you are asking me to create another file in AppData directory(constant path) for storing the 'LastLogin', because when the application is updated the application folder is being modified.

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty much what I sugest

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [Isolated Storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/3ak841sy(v=VS.90).aspx)