# How to serialize and save a GameObject in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a game where the player picks up a weapon and it is then placed as the GameObject variable to my player called "MainHandWeapon" and I am trying to save that weapon through scene changes so I am trying to save it.  How I handle this is as follows :

```
public class Player_Manager : Character, Can_Take_Damage {

    // The weapon the player has.
    public GameObject MainHandWeapon;

    public void Save()
    {
        // Create the Binary Formatter.
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        // Stream the file with a File Stream. (Note that File.Create() 'Creates' or 'Overwrites' a file.)
        FileStream file = File.Create(Application.persistentDataPath + "/PlayerData.dat");
        // Create a new Player_Data.
        Player_Data data = new Player_Data ();
        // Save the data.
        data.weapon = MainHandWeapon;
        data.baseDamage = BaseDamage;
        data.baseHealth = BaseHealth;
        data.currentHealth = CurrentHealth;
        data.baseMana = BaseMana;
        data.currentMana = CurrentMana;
        data.baseMoveSpeed = BaseMoveSpeed;
        // Serialize the file so the contents cannot be manipulated.
        bf.Serialize(file, data);
        // Close the file to prevent any corruptions
        file.Close();
    }
}

[Serializable]
class Player_Data
{
    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject _weapon;
    public GameObject weapon{
        get { return _weapon; }
        set { _weapon = value; }
    }

    public float baseDamage;
    public float baseHealth;
    public float currentHealth;
    public float baseMana;
    public float currentMana;
    public float baseMoveSpeed;
}
```

But I keep getting this error from having this setup :

```
SerializationException: Type UnityEngine.GameObject is not marked as Serializable.
```

What exactly am I doing wrong?

Comment: not an answer, but [here](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/80638/binary-serialization-of-c-for-gameobject-in-unity) is a link to a similar question that has been asnwered. I hope this is of some help.

Comment: Joey, you have to do it "by hand". It's that simple.  there is simply no serialization or "thing saving" in Unity - it's just that simple.  (Note that the so-called "Serialization" class is almost totally useless; it's just not for that purpose.)

Comment: NOTE.

You say "I am trying to save that weapon through scene changes..."

To do that, you very simply use DontDestroyOnLoad.

It's totally commonplace that a character / whatever will move through scenes. There is utterly no need, whatsoever, to save or serlalize it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Aftr hours of experiment, I came to conclusion that Unity **cannot** serialize `GameObject` with `BinaryFormatter`. Unity claims that is possible in their API documentation but it's **not**.

If you want to remove the **error** without removing the  _weapon GameObject, you should replace ...

```
[SerializeField]
private GameObject _weapon;
```

with

```
[NonSerialized]
private GameObject _weapon;
```

This will let the rest of your code run without throwing exception, but you **can't** deserialize `_weapon` GameObject. You can **deserialize** other fields.

**OR**

You can serialize GameObject as **xml**. This can serialize GameObject without any problem. It saves the data in human readable format. If you care about security or don't want players **modifying** scores on their own devices, you can [**encrypt**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7148745/c-sharp-encrypt-text-output), convert it into [binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5664345/string-to-binary-in-c-sharp) or [Base-64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7148745/c-sharp-encrypt-text-output) format before **saving** it to the disk.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.IO;
using System;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Text;

public class Player_Manager : MonoBehaviour
{

    // The weapon the player has.
    public GameObject MainHandWeapon;

    void Start()
    {
        Save();
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        float test = 50;

        Debug.Log(Application.persistentDataPath);

        // Stream the file with a File Stream. (Note that File.Create() 'Creates' or 'Overwrites' a file.)
        FileStream file = File.Create(Application.persistentDataPath + "/PlayerData.dat");
        // Create a new Player_Data.
        Player_Data data = new Player_Data();
        //Save the data.
        data.weapon = MainHandWeapon;
        data.baseDamage = test;
        data.baseHealth = test;
        data.currentHealth = test;
        data.baseMana = test;
        data.currentMana = test;
        data.baseMoveSpeed = test;

        //Serialize to xml
        DataContractSerializer bf = new DataContractSerializer(data.GetType());
        MemoryStream streamer = new MemoryStream();

        //Serialize the file
        bf.WriteObject(streamer, data);
        streamer.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        //Save to disk
        file.Write(streamer.GetBuffer(), 0, streamer.GetBuffer().Length);

        // Close the file to prevent any corruptions
        file.Close();

        string result = XElement.Parse(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(streamer.GetBuffer()).Replace("\0", "")).ToString();
        Debug.Log("Serialized Result: " + result);

    }
}


[DataContract]
class Player_Data
{
    [DataMember]
    private GameObject _weapon;

    public GameObject weapon
    {
        get { return _weapon; }
        set { _weapon = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public float baseDamage;
    [DataMember]
    public float baseHealth;
    [DataMember]
    public float currentHealth;
    [DataMember]
    public float baseMana;
    [DataMember]
    public float currentMana;
    [DataMember]
    public float baseMoveSpeed;
}
```

Comment: *"Aftr hours of experiment, I came to conclusion that Unity cannot serialize GameObject with BinaryFormatter. Unity claims that is possible in their API documentation but it's not."*  I agree with you 100%.

Comment: @JoeBlow And plus there many other people having that same problem. Either there is an error in the documentation or unity spent time writing codes but failed to test it.

Comment: What serializing `List<T>` class or `Object[] foo` using your solution? Will it work too? I tried your solution and it worked on one specific class only but not on array types such as the two examples.

Comment: I really don't know. This answer is for `GameObject;` only. You should test that and see.

Comment: @Programmer I'm happy, relieved and sad to see that you also get infuriated with Unity's consistent inconsistencies. It confirms what I've long thought, that they are careless and uncaring.

Comment: Note that while you *can* serialize the `GameObject` you most probably will not be able to properly deserialaize it again .. you can't simply create instances of a `GameObject` on `c#`-level vi the serializer and expect the underlying Unity C++ engine to catch it up  => You would either get errors or invalid/useless GameObject instances after deserializing. Unity itself uses a complex YAML serialization which uses GUID references (those IDs are stored in the `.meta` files of all assets/scripts/etc)

Answer (score 3):

Unity won't let you do it because a Gameobject comprises of all the scripts attached to it. For instance mesh renderers, colliders etc..

If you wanted to say serialize the Tranform, you could get around this you by making a new Vector3 position, Vector3 scale, Vector4 quaternion and serialize that out instead and then on deserialization feed this data into a new Transform (for instance).

But attempting to serialize the actual mesh data which is associated with the mesh renderer would prove quite the complex task. Better off probably just serializing an int or something which represents a mesh ID and then transmuting this to the correct reference on load.

Comment: Then what does this mean? "- All classes inheriting from UnityEngine.Object, for example GameObject, Component, MonoBehaviour, Texture2D, AnimationClip."  So by that statement I should be able to save a GameObject right? or am I not understanding this?  Also by this statement if I didnt want to save the GameObject I could just save the scripts?  If not I feel what they put is very misleading.

Comment: From where does your quote derive @JoeyL ?

Comment: @JoeyL Other resources: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/803671/i-need-to-save-and-load-gameobjects-how-do-i-do-th.html http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/998574/save-serialize-gameobjects.html  https://www.reddit.com/r/Unity3D/comments/3ic3id/game_object_serialization_in_unity_5/

Comment: They mean serializable into their internal save format, in editor.

Answer (score 2):

Ideally you should have an object which hold the weapon data (attack, durability, etc ...) and serialize this object, it makes your save games much smaller, and is more OOP, as you can inherit from that class.